# How to show value of bar code in text view

Tags: android, textview

i am creating a project that scan bar code and display it for few seconds on screen. when i scan a bar code it shows bar code value on screen and this value is goes after few seconds. i am trying to show value in text view but i cant. i want to show this in text view. any body please guide me about it.
i am new in android studio

here is my code

```
package example.zxing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scannedbarcode);
//
//    public void setTextView(TextView textView) {
//        this.textView = textView;
//    }

public void scanBarcode(View view) {
    new IntentIntegrator((Activity)this).initiateScan();
}

public void scanBarcodeCustomOptions(View view) {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, 
resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the 
fragment
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

/**
 * Sample of scanning from a Fragment
 */
public static class ScanFragment extends Fragment {
    private String toast;

    public ScanFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        displayToast();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, 
 false);
        Button scan = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_from_fragment);
//            TextView textView = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.scannedbarcode);
//            textView.setText("text you want to display");
        scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scanFromFragment();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void scanFromFragment() {
        IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this).initiateScan();
    }

    private void displayToast() {
        if(getActivity() != null && toast != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            toast = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
        IntentResult result = 
IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null) {
            if(result.getContents() == null) {
                toast = "Cancelled from fragment";
            } else {
                toast = "Scanned from fragment: " + result.getContents();
            }

            // At this point we may or may not have a reference to the 
activity
            displayToast();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have the string just settext to textView . Whats the Prob ?

Comment: i cant understand how to set.
please guide me through code
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scannedbarcode);
}
```

then in `onActivityResult` where you toast the barcode scanned do this:

```
textView.setText("SCANNED: "+result.getContents());
```

Comment: it is not working. 
when i scan bar code it shows and after few seconds it goes. not show in text view

Answer (score 0):

Just ad a text view in your activty's xml. Find the text view and set the scanned result to text view.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextViewId);
}
}
```

In **onActivityResult** get content and assign to text view .

```
if(result.getContents() != null) {
       mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(result.getContents()));
    }
```

Comment: .setText give me error as
non-static method 'setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' can not be referenced from a static context

Comment: how could it possible if you are using same instance in same class inside a non-static method. Did you try  mTextView.setText() or something else ?

Comment: i am trying this.
mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(result.getContents()));

Comment: post your xml .

Comment: done. its working fine. thanks for  help ADM and Orcun.

Comment: If it worked, please accept ADM's answer. So that others could see it and use it for their solution.

Comment: yes accepted the answer. but when i click on accept button i can not changed

Comment: Thx you can Accept the answer and upvote for now . It will not count as your repo is just 1 right now .